# If $V$, $E$ and $F$ is respectively the number of vertices, edges and faces in a maximally triangulated graph, then why do we have $3F = 2E$?

Tags: graphs, computational-geometry

Suppose we have a *maximally triangulated graph* $G$, where $V$, $E$ and $F$ is respectively the number of vertices, edges and faces. The following graph should be a maximally triangulated graph.

[image]

Apparently, the equation $3F = 2E$ holds for $G$. Why (intuitively) is this the case?

Answer (score 1):

Every face is a triangle (hence, the name, "maximally triangulated graph"). Every face is thus composed of three edges (or sides). So, if we have $F$ faces, then we may be tempted to say that there are $3F$ edges. This is **not** the case because an edge contributes to exactly $2$ faces. So, in $3F$ we are counting every edge twice. So, $\frac{3F}{2} = E \iff 3F = 2E$.